# In stead of using lots of "puts", how to use "one puts" to write many strings in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pretty-print

I am trying to prettier my code in Ruby. I have used a lot of "puts" like this;

```
  puts "something 1"
  puts "something 2"
  puts "something 3"
```

I try to use one "puts" to write all of this with the same format, I am trying something like this but it does not work;

```
puts << "something 1" << "something 2" << "something 3"
```

Could you please suggest me the better way in stead of writing those things using lots of "puts"?

Answer (score 1):

```
somethings = ['something 1', 'something 2', 'something 3']
puts somethings.join("\n")
```

Comment: Is there any way without creating am array? Just looking for a syntax, writing a puts and printing two strings with just a puts.There couple of puts at couple of different places, i do not wanna create an array for each of them.

Comment: do you want a single newline for the entire result, or a different newline for each string? There are many ways to do this such as heredocs, string interpolation, and string concatenation (i.e. "hello" + "world")

Answer (score 0):

Use `print` to print out all variables in the same line, or `puts` with newline:

```
x = "something"
y = 1
z = true

print x,y,z
print "\n"
puts x,y,z
```

output:

```
something1true
something
1
true
```

If it's all string, you can always concat them using `<<` or `+` like so:

```
puts "something1" + "something2" + "something3"
puts "something1" << "something2" << "something3"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# if you do create an array variable, then here are two more options
stuff = ["something1", "something2", "something3"]
stuff.each { |i| puts i }   # on  seperate lines
puts ("%s " * stuff.size) % stuff # all on one line


# you can still make use of arrays even without a seperate variable
puts ["something1", "something2", "something3"]  # on seperate lines
puts ["something1", "something2", "something3"].join(' ')  # on one line
puts "%s %s %s " % ["something1", "something2", "something3"]  # same as the second option above really

# then there is just concat as mentioned above, but it seems ugly if you want to include spaces
puts "something1" + " " + "something2" + " " + "something3"  # ugly imho
```